# Android: NullPointerException being thrown on Button call?

Tags: java, android, xml

I cannot figure out why but I keep getting `E/AndroidRuntime(709): java.lang.NullPointerException` at any point I try to call the buttons titled yes and no. The buttons are created in an xml layout and called using the `findViewById` method, a similar technique I've used in several properly working buttons in the same program. The only difference between these buttons and the rest is that their xml code is kept in a separate layout file that is not the main.xml.

If I only want to show the buttons and don't call them within the java code they will show up just as they should. The error occurs when I try to apply anything to them in the java code, such as `setClickable()` and `setOnClickListener()`.

The code below outlines the creation of the button and layout in the xml and the java code shows a method that creates a popup when called.

Java Code:

```
    private void getLogoutOption() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.logoutoption, null);  
        final PopupWindow logoutoption = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button yes = (Button) findViewById (R.id.yes);
        yes.setClickable(true);
        yes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                logoutoption.dismiss();
                switchActivity(8);
            }
        });

        Button no = (Button) findViewById (R.id.no);
        no.setClickable(true);
        no.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                logoutoption.dismiss();
            }
        });

    logoutoption.showAsDropDown(search, 50, -30);
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >"

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_default" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logoutmessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Are you sure you would like to logout?"
            android:textColor="@color/gold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/logoutmessage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="YES"
            android:textColor="@color/green" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/logoutmessage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/yes"
            android:text="NO"
            android:textColor="@color/red" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems Button yes = (Button) findViewById (R.id.yes); is returning null. Did you do setContentView(..) on onResume() or onCreate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
Button yes = (Button) findViewById (R.id.yes);
Button no = (Button) findViewById (R.id.no);
```

To:

```
Button yes = (Button) popupView.findViewById (R.id.yes);
Button no = (Button) popupView.findViewById (R.id.no);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button yes = (Button) findViewById (R.id.yes);
```

should be

```
Button yes = (Button) popupView.findViewById (R.id.yes);
```

By default `findViewById()` will be searching your content view for the view with the specified ID (e.g. if you used `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, it will be searching through the main.xml structure for those views). If you're searching an inflated layout, you have to call `findViewById()` on that particular inflated layout.

Answer (score 1):

Hi The problem is you are getting id as you take in Activity.In Activity view created by setContentView(R.layout.main).In Your code you are inflating new view so you should use

Button yes = (Button)popupView.findViewById (R.id.yes);